# ListView without inheriting from ListFragment

Tags: android

All the samples I have seen on ListView using fragment extends from ListFragment. In my case, as I extend my fragment from a base fragment (which cannot inherit from ListFragment), I cannot use ListFragment. Is there a way (or an example) on the below.

1. Fragment which does not inherit from ListFragment
2. This fragment displays a list of items populated through ArrayAdapter
3. I will use a viewholder to display custom layout for each item.

Comment: Can you show how can I achieve the above, or an example showing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a `ListView` in your fragment's XML file